# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'homeHint'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following errors only in Android Studio. Eclipse is working correctly.

Error:No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'homeHint'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'homePageBtn'.

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
<item name="homePageBtn">@style/homePageBtn</item>
    <item name="homeHint">@style/homeHint</item>
</style>

<style name="homePageBtn" parent="@style/homeBtn">
    <item name="android:textSize">42sp</item>
</style>

<style name="homeBtn" parent="@style/android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_btn_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_home_btn_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">42sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: there is no style tag named homeHint. Answered by yourself already...

Answer (score 0):

Please try it out. Just click on the button with an arrow in the image and then select "Devices Default" and click OK. Tell me if it works! :)

[image]